# Qt event when switching desktops

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I am currently using a Mac to test my software, I have a fullscreen Qt window that opens a floating Qt::Tool on top of it. I would love for the Qt::Tool to be linked to the fullscreen window, however when switching between desktops (three-finger swipe), the Qt::Tool is displayed on the other desktops although its parent window is in fullscreen in another desktop.

Is there an event that handles switching desktops so that I know when a window is no longer in focus and hide its child windows/tools?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Aren't you using some set of window flags that leads to this behaviour? Try to change those and see if you can get it to work like you want. I bet Mac handles one of the window flags you set in a special way such that it carries across virtual desktops.

Comment: That was it ! I was using Qt::Tool instead of Qt::Dialog

Comment: I went ahead and made it into an answer you can accept ;). Glad to be of help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably using some set of window flags that leads to this behaviour. Try to change those and see if you can get it to work like you want. I bet Mac handles one of the window flags you set in a special way such that it carries across virtual desktops.